# Public variable appears empty in the test method of a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

I am trying to get the value of the variable "listAccountsTest" in the "static void test" method. This variable will be used in the "System.assertEquals" method as the expected value, but it is empty. This is strange because after using it in the "insert" command I can see in the debug that it still has values.

Can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```java
@isTest
private class ContaAtualizaMatrizBatchTest {
    
    public static Id contaId = null;
    public static List<Account> listaContasTest = new List<Account>();
    
    @testSetup
    static void setup() {
     
        listaContasTest.add(new Account(name='Account ', Codigo_Clifor_Cliente__c='300000'));
        
        Account conta = null;
        
        for (Integer i=1;i<10;i++) {
            conta = new Account(name='Account '+i, Cod_Clifor_Matriz__c='300000', Codigo_Clifor_Cliente__c='40000'+i+'');
            listaContasTest.add(conta);
        }
        
        insert listaContasTest;
        contaId = listaContasTest[0].id;
        System.debug('listaContasTest = '+ listaContasTest);
        
    }
    @isTest static void test() {
        
        Test.startTest();
        ContaAtualizaMatrizBatch cambt = new ContaAtualizaMatrizBatch();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(cambt);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        System.debug('listaContasTest no metodo de Test = '+ listaContasTest);
        System.assertEquals(listaContasTest, [SELECT Name, ParentId FROM Account WHERE ParentId =: contaId]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables set in an `@testSetup` method are always cleared before running individual test methods.

It's annoying, but that's the direction that Salesforce took. The way I get around this in my tests is to have an unannotated static method to do any common querying/variable setup

example

```java
@isTest 
private class MyTest{
    static Map<Id, Account> insertedAccounts;

    @testSetup
    static void makeData(){
        insert new Account(Name = 'testAccount');
    }

    // This is the addtional method that we call at the start of every test to
    //   make sure that data is populated in our static variables.
    // Annoying, but querying is purported to be faster than inserting test records
    static void doSetup(){
        insertedAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
    }

    @isTest
    static void aUnitTest(){
        system.debug(insertedAccounts); // will print nothing/null
        doSetup();
        system.debug(insertedAccounts); // will actually print something

        // Perform the rest of your test here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Derek F

Comment: @DiegoDamasceno See also [my idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC). I'm hoping they fix it one day.